# What is the best way to make the matrix operations more faster in python

Tags: python, optimization

While I am evluating the excution time in my code, I found the following three lines took almost 99% of the running time, so my goal is to optimize these three lines of code.

The details about the following code is: 
    R, P, Q are both sparse matrix, I use scipy.sparse.lil_matrix, data type is np.float64, 
    and alpha, beta are just float constant.

```
eij = R[i, j] - np.dot(P[i, :], Q[:, j])                             (~9s)
    for k in range(K):                                               (~11s)
         P[i, k] += alpha * (2 * eij * Q[k, j] - beta * P[i, k])
         Q[k, j] += alpha * (2 * eij * P[i, k] - beta * Q[k, j])
```

How could I make them run much faster!!!???

Comment: try [numexpr](http://code.google.com/p/numexpr/)

Comment: @JBernardo: Cool! Much easier than [`pyopencl`](http://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/)

Comment: @JBernardo submit as an answer?

Comment: @JBernardo I tried numexpr, I don't think it really fit this specific situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that numpy has optimize the matrix-type operation, so retwrite the code as:

```
eij = rating_train[i, j] - np.dot(P[i, :], Q[:, j])
P[i, :] += alpha * (2 * eij * Q[:, j] - beta * P[i, :])
Q[:, j] += alpha * (2 * eij * P[i, :] - beta * Q[:, j])
```

This is about 1 time faster than the original code. But I am still not satisfied about it..